# Spring MVC as ROOT Application in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, tomcat, root

I have a Spring MVC application and I'm trying to make it work as ROOT in tomcat in order to access: www.mydomain  instead of www.mydomann/app-name.

My  tomcat 6 configuration files does not have change, so I think it unnecessary to show them here.

My local machine is windows and simply renaming my .war to ROOT.war and putting it in the webapps folder works perfectly. However my production server is Linux and not working. In production it seems that the application can not start servet or something else, because the friendly urls from the controllers do not responds.

I've read a lot of questions here but still could not solve my case.

thank's!

Comment: Define "not working". Any exception in the browser? Have you checked the tomcat logs?

Comment: The requests to Controllers urls returns 404 error.

Not Found

The requested URL /mycontroller was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: And what do the tomcat logs say?

Comment: Change the app.war to ROOT.war is not a good idea, you should use Tomcat's configuration to make it as the ROOT application.

Comment: the logs  dont show errors..
see my catalina.out:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1__-EhgiklzVt-OtZgdLGKPMloHeO4BEIk_Z6I8BN5xE/edit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web server in front of tomcat? If so then the normal practice would be to have url rewrite rules configured on the web server, rather than naming your application ROOT.

Answer (score -1):

modify the server.xml

before the tag   . insert the below code
`<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\hlue" workDir="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\work"/>`

like this.
`<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\hlue" workDir="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\work"/>

      </Host>`

restart the tomcat. that will be ok

Comment: Those paths aren't applicable to the Linux server where the problem is occurring